# Edge-connectivity of edge-transitive graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-connectivity

If $G$ is a connected vertex-transitive graph then it is well known that the edge connectivity of $G$, $\kappa'(G)$ equals to $\rm{val}(G)$ -  the degree of a vertex in $G$ (note that $G$ is regular.) My question is the following

> Is $\kappa'(G) = \delta(G)$ for every connected edge-transitive graph $G$ that is not necessarily vertex-transitive?

The claim appears to be true after testing it on some of the known edge-transitive graphs (that are not vertex-transitive). However I do not see an obvious way to modify the proof for vertex-transitive graphs to make it work for this case as well.

Is the claim true? Could someone give a hint for its proof ?

Comment: I suspect that edge-connectivity does equal minimum valency for edge-transitive graphs. I also suspect that the usual proof of this for vertex-transitive graphs can be extended to this case. Since this is a nice question, I think I will assign it to my graduate class, and so I will not be more explicit here.